# Choice function and well ordering

Tags: set-theory, well-orders

Let A ≠ ∅ and **f : P(A) \ {∅} → A** is a choice function for **P(A) \ {∅}**.

Prove that the following two conditions are equivalent:

- **∀B∀C(B ≠ ∅ & B ⊆ A & C ≠ ∅ & C ⊆ A ⇒ f(B∪C) = f({f(B), f(C)}));**
- exists such a well order **≤ in A**, that for each non empty B in A it holds that **f(B) = min ≤ B**

My attempt:

From **f : P(A) \ {∅} → A ⇒ Dom(f)=P(A)\ {∅}**.

Hence Let **F={f|f : P(A) \ {∅} → A (∀a∈Dom(f))[f(a)∈a]}**.
**<F,⊆F >** is partial ordered set in which every chain has an upper bound.

Indeed, let **F'⊆F** is a chain. Then for every **f∈F',f⊆∪F'**.

Since **F'** is a chain of functions, then **∪F'** also is a function and **Dom(∪F')=∪(Dom(f)|f∈F'}⊆P(A)\ {∅}** and for every  **a∈Dom(∪F'),∪F'(a)∈a**.
Then **(∪F')∈F**  and as such it is an upperbound for the chain F'.

And now **∪(B,C)∈F'⊂f**. So **f((B∪C))=f({f(B),f(C)})**.

But I do not know how to go further.
Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot make any sense of your argument. If you’re trying to prove that the first statement implies the second, you cannot look at a whole family of choice functions: you’re given one specific choice function, and you have to use it to construct a well-ordering of $A$. And if you’re trying to prove the other direction, you must simply define $f(S)=\min_\le S$ for each non-empty $S\subseteq A$ and show that this $f$ has the desired property. That direction is quite trivial, and I’ll leave it to you.

For the other direction, assume that such a choice function $f$ exists. Define a relation $\le$ on $A$ by setting $a\le b$ iff $f(\{a,b\})=a$. We first prove that $\le$ is a partial order on $A$. Reflexivity and antisymmetry are easy.

For each $a\in A$ it is certainly true that $f(\{a,a\})=f(\{a\})=a$, so $a\le a$, and $\le$ is reflexive. And if $a,b\in A$, $a\le b$, and $b\le a$, then $a=f(\{a,b\})=b$, so $\le$ is antisymmetric.

Proving transitivity takes a bit more work.

If $a,b,c\in A$, $a\le b$, and $b\le c$, then $f(\{a,b\})=a$ and $f(\{b,c\})=b$. Thus,

$$\begin{align*}
f(\{a,b,c\})&=f\big(\{a,b\}\cup\{b,c\}\big)\\
&=f\big(\big\{f(\{a,b\}),f(\{b,c\})\big\}\big)\\
&=f(\{a,b\})\\
&=a\,.
\end{align*}$$

On the other hand,

$$\begin{align*}
f(\{a,b,c\})&=f\big(\{a,c\}\cup\{b,c\}\big)\\
&=f\big(\big\{f(\{a,c\}),f(\{b,c\})\big\}\big)\\
&=f\big(\big\{f(\{a,c\}),b\big\}\big)\,,
\end{align*}$$

so $f\big(\big\{f(\{a,c\}),b\big\}\big)=a$, and therefore $f(\{a,c\})=a$ and hence $a\le c$.

Clearly $\le$ is linear: for any $a,b\in A$, $f(\{a,b\})\in\{a,b\}$, so either $a\le b$, or $b\le a$. It only remains to show that $\le$ is a well-order. Let $\varnothing\ne S\subseteq A$, and for convenience let $s_0=f(S)$. Suppose that $s_0\ne\min_\le S$; then there is an $s\in S$ such that $s<s_0$, i.e., $f(\{s,s_0\})=s$. This is impossible if $S=\{s,s_0\}$ (why?), so $S\setminus\{s,s_0\}\ne\varnothing$. Let $R=S\setminus\{s,s_0\}$; then

$$\begin{align*}
f(\{s,f(R)\})&=f\big(\big\{f(\{s,s_0\}),f(R)\big\}\big)\\
&=f(\{s,s_0\}\cup R)\\
&=f(S)\\
&=s_0\,,
\end{align*}$$

which is impossible, since $s\ne s_0\ne f(R)$. Thus, $s_0\le s$ for each $s\in S$, and hence $s_0=\min_\le S$. Every non-empty subset of $A$ therefore has a $\le$-minimum element, and $\le$ well-orders $A$.

Comment: Thank you so much! Amazing solution. I was trying to use the general case of the property of f and then to apply it  for B and C. However, as you have said it does not really make sense. About the "This is impossible if S={s,s0} (why?)", I think that it is because it means that there is a smaller element that the smallest-absurd. Will try to prove on my own the other inclusion and will post it.

Comment: @Tiki: There was a typo, now fixed, in the part leading up to the *why?* question. It’s impossible because $s_0$ is (now that I’ve fixed the typo) defined to be $f(S)$, so if $S=\{s,s_0\}$, then $f(\{s,s_0\})=s_0$, and therefore $s_0\le s$.

Comment: Please look at my try to prove the other direction: My attempt for (ii)↦(i):
Define f(s)=min≤s for ∀s⊆A.
Let s'=f(s)=min≤s⇒s' is a minimal element of S in regard to ≤, so ≤ is a well order⇒ ≤ is a linear order. Therefore for ∀a,b∈A it holds : f({a,b})∈{a,b}=a∪b.
But by def f({a,b})=min≤{a,b} which is a if a≤b and b if b≤a. Hence f preserves the order and f({f(a),f(b)})=min≤{f(a),f(b)}. WLOG let  f({f(a),f(b)})=f({a})=a,hence f(a)≤f(b). Now f(a∪b)=f({a,b})=a since (a)≤f(b). Then we proved that f(a∪b)=f({f(a),f(b)}) for a≤b.

Comment: Hello.Would you please check whether or not my solution is correct?